# Password Recovery throught Email in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I am trying to implement password recovery in ASP.NET Web application but something is wrong.
I am using this code -

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            await configSendGridasync(message);
        }

        // Use NuGet to install SendGrid (Basic C# client lib) 
        private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
            myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
            myMessage.From = new MailAddress(
                                "mymail@gmail.com", "Joe S.");
            myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
            myMessage.PlainTextContent = message.Body;
            myMessage.HtmlContent = message.Body;

            var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
                       );

            // Create a Web transport for sending email.
            var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

            // Send the email.
            if (transportWeb != null)
            {
                await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
                await Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

But

```
myMessage.From = new MailAddress(
                                    "mymail@gmail.com", "Joe S.");
```

Is giving error **cs0029 Cannot implicitly convert type system.Net.MailAdress to SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Adress**

Also,  in line `var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);` Web is not found.

Do any have idea what is wrong ?
SendGrid Nuget package is installed.

Comment: Answer for the first question is posted below. Can you raise the 2nd question in a new SO post. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is picking up `MailAddress` from the `System.Net` namespace. You need to resolve this from the `SendGrid.Helper.Mail` namespace instead.

Or you are creating `MailAddress` when you should be passing `Address`;

There are a number of ways to achieve this, most simply;

```
myMessage.From = new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Address("mymail@gmail.com", "Joe S.");
```

Looking at the SendGrid docs you might also want to consider using `EmailAddress` instead of `MailAddress` or `Address`.

https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-csharp-code-example/

```
var to = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
```

Comment: When I used your example compiler state that Helper do not exist.

Comment: Do you have a `using` statement for the send-grid library?

Comment: I have it like this - using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail

Comment: Typo in my code? Is it `Helpers` rather than `Helper`?

Comment: Also, check if you should be using `EmailAddress` class instead of `MailAddress` or `Address`. Take a look at this example; https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-csharp-code-example/

Comment: `var to = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");`

Comment: Yes EmailAdress was right. No Error. Appreciate your time !